# Elasticsearch bulk import of json data error: curl: (5) Could not resolve proxy: POST

Tags: json, curl, elasticsearch

I have Elasticsearch running locally and I'm trying to dump some JSON data to play around with but my bulk dump isn't working? I can't seem to find anything regarding this error. I'm guessing it doesn't have anything to do with my code. My code:

```
curl -xPOST 'localhost:9200/_bulk?pretty' --data-binary @indeed_profiles.json
```

Error:

```
curl: (5) Could not resolve proxy: POST
```

Anyone has any ideas?

EDIT: I found my error. I should have used -XPOST instead of -xPOST -.-